# Remove rows with duplicate value for a column in SQL

Tags: sql

[image]

From the above table, I want to remove the rows that have the duplicate `CODE` column. Out of the duplicate rows, the row with the smallest `ID_CHECK` should be retained.

Output:

[image]

Comment: What is the DBMS you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this should be your SQL query:

```
Select Names, Code, ID_CHECK
FROM
(
Select Names, Code, ID_CHECK, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by Name,Code Order By ID_CHECK) as rnk
FROM table
)tmp
WHERE tmp.rnk=1;
```

Let me know if this works.